# Java library to generate TomTom GPS poi data

Tags: java, tomtom

I wonder, if there exists any Java library, which could generate poi-data for Tomtom navigation devices (usually the file has .ov2 extension).

I use Tomtom makeov2.exe util from Tomtom, but it is not stable and it seems that not longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to find a library that does writing, although I did find this class to read `.ov2` files:

```
package readers;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class OV2RecordReader {

    public static String[] readOV2Record(FileInputStream inputStream){
        String[] record = null;
        int b = -1;
        try{
            if ((b = inputStream.read())> -1) {
                // if it is a simple POI record
                if (b == 2) {
                    record = new String[3];
                    long total = readLong(inputStream);

                    double longitude = (double) readLong(inputStream) / 100000.0;
                    double latitude = (double) readLong(inputStream) / 100000.0;

                    byte[] r = new byte[(int) total - 13];
                    inputStream.read(r);

                    record[0] = new String(r);
                    record[0] = record[0].substring(0,record[0].length()-1);
                    record[1] = Double.toString(latitude);
                    record[2] = Double.toString(longitude);
                }
                //if it is a deleted record
                else if(b == 0){
                    byte[] r = new byte[9];
                    inputStream.read(r);
                }
                //if it is a skipper record
                else if(b == 1){
                    byte[] r = new byte[20];
                    inputStream.read(r);
                }
                else{
                    throw new IOException("wrong record type");
                }
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return record;
    }

    private static long readLong(FileInputStream is){
        long res = 0;
        try{
            res = is.read();
            res += is.read() <<8;
            res += is.read() <<16;
            res += is.read() <<24;
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

I also found this PHP code to write the file:

```
<?php
$csv = file("File.csv");
$nbcsv = count($csv);
$file = "POI.ov2";
$fp = fopen($file, "w");
for ($i = 0; $i < $nbcsv; $i++) {
    $table = split(",", chop($csv[$i]));
    $lon = $table[0];
    $lat = $table[1];
    $des = $table[2];
    $TT = chr(0x02).pack("V",strlen($des)+14).pack("V",round($lon*100000)).pack("V",round($lat*100000)).$des.chr(0x00);
    @fwrite($fp, "$TT");
}
fclose($fp);
```

I'm not sure how you'd go about writing a Java class (or extending the one above) to write the file like the PHP function does, but you may be able to get some insight into how the file is encoded from it.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. But to tell the truth i would prefer  some ready to use, tested, supported library, and not to write a new one from scratch.

Comment: This answer helped me work out my problem, though TomTom ov2 files appear to contain extended type 3 as well.